# Direct3D 11 (Vortice) stutters in Windows.Forms Control (works fine in Form or WinUI)

Tags: c#, direct3d, direct3d11, vortice

I am using the window handle of a Windows.Forms.Control to draw 3D data using the Vortice library.

It takes about 1 or 2 seconds to draw one frame which is very slow of course. The individual draws are very fast though (analyzed using the graphics debugger).

The same code works fine when using the window handle of a dedicated Form. It also works fine in WinUI (but then, the swap chain is also initialized differently of course).

This might be trivial so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you 0lease share the code? Ideally a [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron: thanks for pushing me into doing this. I found the error this way.

Comment: Good. It is quite often a way to fix an error - to find the mre =) Do not forget to post your answer!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason we were using InvalidateRect instead of Invalidate and that caused the flickering and stuttering.